# Do you need to cast spells every day you are working on a construct?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, crafting, spellcasting, constructs

Crafting magic items takes one day for every 1,000 gold pieces of its value and spells have to be cast every day. Although it takes one day for every 1,000 gold pieces to craft a construct as well, I can find no mention that you have to cast the required spells every day.

Can I nonetheless assume that spells have to be cast every day to craft a construct?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You generally can’t do anything else useful on those days anyway, so I’m not clear what implications you’re looking at.

Comment: I am having a dispute with one of my players on this. His character does not know the appropriate spells, but can acquire and use them as scrolls. Now my take is that you cannot use only one scroll, but have to use one every day, much the same way as it specifically says with magic items. He has however correctly noted that nothing states this rule specifically as it does with magic items.

Comment: [Question-adjacent.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59995/8610)

Comment: I knew about the dedicated wright, but it specifically uses other mechanics so as to provide the players with a workaround. As far as I know it does not deal with my problem as such, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

**RAW spells do not have to be cast every day while creating a construct**

In [Creating Magic Items](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm) it is specifically statet that spells have to be cast every day. Here is an example for armors:

> The act of working on the armor triggers the prepared spells, making them unavailable for casting during each day of the armor’s creation.

Nothing of the kind is statet for [crafting constructs](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Craft_Construct):

> The creature can create any construct whose prerequisites it meets. Enchanting a
>   construct takes one day for each 1,000 gp in its market price. To
>   enchant a construct, a spellcaster must spend 1/25 the item's price in
>   XP and use up raw materials costing half of this price. The creature
>   can repair constructs that have taken damage. In one day of work, the
>   creature can repair up to 20 points of damage by expending 50 gp per
>   point of damage repaired. A newly created construct has average hit
>   points for its Hit Dice.

It also cannot be found in all the entries for different constructs in the MM and neither is it stated in the WotC Archive on [crafting construct](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20050816a) rules (although it is specifically stated again in the [magic item creation](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20041207a/) entry).

The Monster Manual also states the following things:

Monster Manual p.134:

> Creating a golem is essentially similar to creating any sort of magic item.

however it also states this:

> Completing the golem’s creation drains the appropriate XP from the creator and requires casting any spells **on the final day**.

Monster Manual II p.115 states:

> The real work of creation involves extended magical rituals requiring two months to complete. Understanding the rituals requires a character of the appropriate level with the Craft Magic Arms and Armor and Craft Wondrous Item feats.

This does not specifically say anything about casting the required spells. Also this specific part about the construction of Golems states that the spells have to be cast on the final day, just as the Monster Manual does.

The construction section on every Golem in Monster Manual II affirms this again. Consider this example of the Brass Golem (p.117).

> Completion of the ritual drains 4,000 XP from the creator and requires the *geas/quest, limited wish, maze, Mordekainen's sword and polymorph any object* spell.

Thus this suggests that the spells only have to be cast at the end of the ritual rather than every day.

[Pathfinder](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-construct-item-creation/) (although being a different rule system than RAW 3.5) specifically states that the spells have to be cast every day, although they can be omitted by raising the craft DC by 5:

> The act of working on the construct expends the prepared spells, making them unavailable for casting during each day of the construct’s creation (that is, those spell slots are expended from the caster’s currently prepared spells, just as if they had been cast.) For each spell requirement you do not meet, the DC to craft the construct increases by 5.

Comment: Craft Construct is an Item Creation feat, and so inherits the need to cast (actually, lose-without-casting) the spell every day.

Comment: Where does it say that though? I instinctively agree on what you say, but whereas these things are specifically stated for all magic items, it is not stated for constructs (and outright contradicted for golems in the MM). So if you have a RAW quote of this rule I would be grateful.

Comment: @KRyan I've been struggling with this for days, but I think this is actually the right answer.  Reread [**Creating Magic Items**](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#creating-magic-items) (*DMG* 282). No mention of spells until each specific kind of magic item. Reread [**Prerequisites**](http://dndsrd.net/magicItems.html#prerequisites) and it only talks about daily uses of magic items to meet prerequisite spells, not actually casting the spells. I think Andy Collins might've forgotten to include elsewhere language like the golem's or forgot to include a Creating Constructs section.

Comment: In addition to the RAI indication given by the daily magic item expenditure referenced above, [Monte Cook](https://web.archive.org/web/20070824113749/http://www.montecook.com/arch_dmonly4.html), lead designer of the DMG, says spells must be cast every day. But yeah, RAW don't say that.